# Fortran equivalent of the MATLAB meshgrid function?

Tags: matlab, fortran

Is there a `meshgrid` equivalent in Fortran?

This is the Matlab code which I am trying to re-write in Fortran:

```
n = a;  %same in fortran
m = n*(n-1)/2; %same in fortran 
offdiags = dec2bin(0:2^m-1,m)-48; % found a subroutine online
A = zeros(n,n,2^m); %multi-dimensional array same concept in fortran

[ind_i,ind_j,ind_k] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n,1:2^m); % ?
A(ind_i>ind_j) = offdiags.'; 

A = A + permute(A,[2 1 3]);
```

This code is intended to generate all the possible adjacency matrices (or graph configurations with undirected edges) with $n$ vertices. The number of such configurations is exactly $2^{n(n-1)/2}$. They can be generated by "hand" in a loop or simply by using the above code kindly suggested on stackoverflow.

For n=3, meshgrid is used in this code to generate 3D coordinate arrays ind_i, ind_j and ind_z which have 3 lines (length(1:3)) , 3 columns (length(1:3)) and 8 pages (length(1:1:2^m)) and they contain copies of the vectors specified in the grid. In my case, let $L=[1,2,3]$. Then I get for i from 1 to 8, $ind_i(:,:,i)=[L;L;L]$, $ind_j(:,:,i)=[ones(1,3);2*ones(1,3);3*ones(1,3)]$ and $ind_k(:,:,i)=i*ones(3)$.

> Matlab description copied from their site: [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv) produces three-dimensional coordinate arrays. The output coordinate arrays X, Y, and Z contain copies of the grid vectors xgv, ygv, and zgv respectively. The sizes of the output arrays are determined by the length of the grid vectors. For grid vectors xgv, ygv, and zgv of length M, N, and P respectively, X, Y, and Z will have N rows, M columns, and P pages.

Comment: At least a sentence about what the function actually does would be in order.

Comment: thank you I just edited my post

Comment: @AlexanderVogt yes this is why I quoted the text, but I can change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Fortran does not have a `meshgrid` intrinsic. 
However, here is a simple implementation of `meshgrid` in 3D using the [`spread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SPREAD.html) intrinsic:

```
subroutine meshgrid(xgv, ygv, zgv, X, Y, Z)
  implicit none
  real,intent(in)   :: xgv(:), ygv(:), zgv(:)
  real,intent(out)  :: X(:,:,:), Y(:,:,:), Z(:,:,:)
  integer           :: sX, sY, sZ, i

  sX = size(xgv) ; sY = size(ygv) ; sZ = size(zgv)

  do i=1,sZ
    X(:,:,i) = spread( xgv, 1, sY )
    Y(:,:,i) = spread( ygv, 2, sX )
  enddo ! i
  do i=1,sX
    Z(i,:,:) = spread( zgv, 1, sY)
  enddo ! i
end subroutine
```

Tested against Octave (I don't have Matlab available).

---

The operations for `Y` and `Z` can be written as one line:

```
  Y = reshape( spread( ygv, 2, sX*sZ ), [sX,sY,sZ] )
  Z = reshape( spread( zgv, 1, sX*sY ), [sX,sY,sZ] )
```

Comment: I get an error when compiling this - it says Error: Symbol ‘sy’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type - and same for the other parameters. What could it be (I'm a total beginner with Fortran)? Also, can you write a code for a 2D meshgrid? (I need the xgv and the ygv only).